# Исключения Proguard при обфускации

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, proguard, library

Решил обфусцировать код приложения, но при работе начали появляться ошибки связанные с библиотеками. Работаю в Android Studio собираю проект через Gradle. Вот список используемых библиотек:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.1.0'
```

Что и где нужно прописать чтобы эти библиотеки не подвергались обфускации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть готовые правила для популярных библиотек, например [proguard snippets](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/tree/master/libraries) или [AAR proguards](https://github.com/yongjhih/android-proguards).

Кроме того, качественно сделанная библиотека обычно включает в себя раздел с правилами для ProGuard, стоит посмотреть доступную документацию к библиотеке.
Например, Firebase - раздел стартгида [Optional: Configure ProGuard](https://firebase-dot-google-developers.appspot.com/docs/database/android/start/). Этим рекомендациям стоит следовать в первую очередь.

Если никаких официальных рекомендаций нет, остается гуглить или самостоятельно решать конфликты

Так же стоит [изучить руководство](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage) по самому инструменту ProGuard